# How can I fix this small issue when making rounded tab links?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Here is a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pzvdv/

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">OUR APPROACH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GET IN TOUCH</a></li>    
</ul>

#navigation {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li {    
    background-color: #934B00;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#navigation li a:link {
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Notice how I can click the link if I'm careful, but when I click the "tab pill" itself, the link isn't clicked.

Any workaround or better ways to accomplish this visual effect?

I want to follow the link href whether the user clicks the actual letters or the container pill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The padding and other styles have to move from `<li>` to `<a>`.
On top of that, you have to add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to the anchor.

Currently, your code does not work as expected, because the padding on the `<li>` adds a gap between the `<li>`s border and the anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/Pzvdv/9/

```
#navigation li {    
    color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

#navigation li a:link {
    display: block;               /* Or inline-block */
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #934B00;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add some padding to the link element like so:

```
#navigation li a {
    padding:5px
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Hey thanks that solved it more or less. I also had to **remove the padding of the `li` element** as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set a to display as a block, i.e.:

```
a { display:block; }
```

And add height/width to 100%, and move all padding to there too. That will make it fill the entire list item.

Answer (score 0):

The css for the link needs to be applied to the anchor instead.

```
#navigation li {    
    float: left;
 }

#navigation li a {
  color: White;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #934B00;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  color: White;=
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Pzvdv/17/

Answer (score 0):

You're adding all the presentation styles to the `li` elements instead of the actual links, just switch them and your pill menu works fine:

```
#navigation li {
    float:left;
}

#navigation li a {    
    background-color: #934B00;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should style the `<a>` element itself.

```
#navigation {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#navigation li a:link {
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #934B00;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```